# Unordered N records for each group of grouped results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing user records, and I want to take 5 records per `user_id`. I don't care about any sort of order. I could do this to get 1 record per user:

> SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY user_id

I could also do something with [user variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/326402) to take the top N records. However, my database is very large and a query with user variables isn't efficiently using the index on the `user_id` column because it has to sort within each group. I don't care about order at all, so I shouldn't have to touch records that aren't relevant. Since I only want 5 and each user has 200-400 records, this is a big performance hit.

Is there a way to write this query efficiently?

This question is **not** the same as asking how to get the top N records, because I don't care about ordering and I believe that removing that restriction should allow an efficient rewriting. If this is not the case, please explain why not. I have clarified this in the title.

Comment: You can also create a loop with distinct user_id and get and store limit 5 records of each user in temporary table, at last select from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out with the below query.
The sub query will number the row based on the column mentioned in the **Order By** clause. In the outer query you can give the filter criteria.

```
SET @rowNum = NULL, @rowVal = NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        *, 
        @rowNum := IF(@rowVal = userid, @rowNum + 1, 1) AS Rno,
        @rowVal := userid AS Dummy
    FROM Yourtable
    ORDER BY [user_id] 
) AS t
 WHERE Rno <= 5
```

Comment: Will this run on MySQL?

Comment: This would query the entire table *before* filtering the rows

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this using a view along with a Partition:

Create a view querying the core table ( add a RowId column counting how many records per user_id):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User_id) AS RowID
FROM Records
```

**lets assume you call the view above ^ "Recordsvw**"

It's simple, now of you need only 5 records per user_id query the view that you created above like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Recordsvw
WHERE ROwID <= 5
```

Comment: Does MySQL really support ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION?

Comment: Im sorry you can't use the exact snippet on MySQL. Please look at the link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/. This link explain how to simulate ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL. Sorry again.

Comment: MySQL has announced that they intend to implement windowing functions in MySQL 8, but that's at least months away.

Comment: Having that function built in will be deff better than improvising it 